# bit to bit xor with same input vector in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I want to do bit by bit xor with same input vector like:

`input(0) xor input(2) xor input(3)` up to `input(187)`.

The answer I get is like:

`output(0) downto output (94)`

This means I have to do `xor` successively. If I have `10` input bits, the last answer I get is `5` bit output. Its very difficult and not a good approach to write the whole vector.

Does anyone knows how to write a efficient code of this in vhdl?

I have a idea how to do it. First extract even index bits, then odd index bits and do `xor` but no luck please help me.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected outputs? I'm not sure why `input(1)` is skipped in your example and yet inputs 0,2 and 3 are involved together. And why the result is 95 outputs. Maybe simplify the example and (again) give inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: I guess he means parallel 2-input XOR gates for a long vector input

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: I imagine that `input(1)` being skipped is a typo.

Comment: @sharth - if it's what Garp's suggesting, there are so many fencepost errors *and* typographical errors that if you can devine the original intent, go into fortune telling.

Comment: Having re-read the question a few more times (it really does need work) - are you trying to compute *parity*?

Comment: See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20296276/and-all-elements-of-an-n-bit-array-in-vhdl)?

Comment: first i want to extract the values that are on odd index than those that are on even index so if i have std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) it means i have 10 indexes first i want to extract 5 even index values than 5 odd index values than do xor.

Comment: @hassananwar: You're going to need to do what Damien asked 21 hours ago. It's difficult to understand exactly what you are asking for, and a great way to help us understand is to use __examples__.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need either a [generate statement](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/generate.html) or a [for loop](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/for_loop.html).

#### Concurrent Statement

```
lots_of_xor: for i in 0 to 94 generate
    output(i) <= input(2*i + 0) xor input(2*i + 1);
end generate;
```

#### Sequential Statement

```
for i in 0 to 94 loop
    output(i) <= input(2*i + 0) xor input(2*i + 1);
end loop;
```

#### Notes

In either version, we can replace 94 with `output'length` as well.

Comment: first i want to extract the values that are on odd index than those that are on even index so if i have std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) it means i have 10 indexes first i want to extract 5 even index values than 5 odd index values than do xor.